# Using Stack in flutter, how do I keep a consistent style across taller screen sizes?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I'm having trouble building a UI in flutter. It's essentially a welcome screen with SVG elements stacked together in a `Stack`, and slightly positioned using `Positioned`. I'm able to build this for a smaller screen size here (iPhone 11):

[image]

However when building for a larger device (iPad Mini and above), this is the result:

[image]

Which is not entirely correct. I want to be able to have a layout similar to the smaller screen across *all screens*, where the SVG is always affixed to the top of this white container.

Here is my code:

```dart
  Widget _body(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      color: Color(0xFFE5E5E5),
      width: double.infinity,
      child: _buildWelcomeImage(context),
    );
  }

  Widget _buildWelcomeImage(BuildContext context) {
    final width = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
    final height = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;
    var blockSizeHorizontal = (width / 100);
    var blockSizeVertical = (height / 100);

    return Stack(
      children: [
        Positioned.fill(
          top: blockSizeVertical * 7,
          child: Align(
            alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
            child: SvgPicture.asset(
              'assets/svg/login.svg',
              alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
              width: width,
              fit: BoxFit.fill,
            ),
          ),
        ),
        Positioned(
            top: blockSizeVertical * 6,
            left: blockSizeHorizontal * 3,
            child: Text('Logo here')
        Positioned.fill(child: _buildWelcomeActions(context)),
      ],
    );
  }

  Widget _buildWelcomeActions(BuildContext context) {
    final width = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
    final height = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;
    var blockSizeVertical = (height / 100);

    return Align(
      alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
      child: FractionallySizedBox(
        heightFactor: 0.4,
        child: Container(
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            color: Colors.white,
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
              topLeft: Radius.circular(90),
            ),
          ),
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [
              Text(
                'copy copy',
                style: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 38,
                  height: 1.2,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                ),
              ),
              Text(
                'copy.',
                style: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 38,
                  color: AppColors.Primary,
                  height: 1.2,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                ),
              ),
              Container(
                padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                  top: blockSizeVertical * 2,
                  bottom: blockSizeVertical * 4,
                ),
                child: Text(
                  'copy copy copy',
                  style: GoogleFonts.workSans(
                    textStyle: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 20,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              _buildButtons(context),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Is there something I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Try to reduce the height on wide screen

Answer (score 0):

You're not doing anything wrong per se but because the aspect ratio between the phone and the table are different, when you use `BoxFit.fill` for the SVG fit it's going to scale up to "fill" the available space causing the positioning to be different.

Any suggestions I have would alter your design:

**A.** Instead of relying on `MediaQuery` to get the device's dimensions, control the aspect ratio of the container yourself based on your SVG and have it boxed in someway that meets your design's needs.

**B.** Have assets that fit common aspect ratios... this has obvious downfalls e.g. how many aspect ratios do you want to support.

**C.** Instead of using the `.4` height factor for the control container, calculate the factor based on the ratio so that it aligns with the asset. This will shrink your controls quite a bit though.

Comment: What would be the alternative?

Comment: I added some suggestions but ultimately it's up to you (and your designers?) to either come up with a solution that translates across devices of different aspect ratios or you're going to need to add logic to have different layouts on different aspect ratios.